# Is there a way to empty $HOME's Trash from the Live CD or Root?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, delete, trash

In an effort to recover data from a troublesome external hard drive, I accidentally filled up my Home folder with recovered data. I managed to send it to the trash, but then I didn't have enough free disk space to empty it. Now I don't have enough free space to even boot the desktop.  From the Live CD's GParted I can see that there is -no- space left on that partition. What can I do from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trash is usually located in `~/.local/share/Trash`. If you can login using a TTY, or mount the partition containing your home directory, that's the folder you want to delete:

```
rm -r .local/share/Trash
```

If you mounted your partition on a live CD, you would need to do:

```
rm -r /media/ubuntu/<Partition Name>/home<your user name>/.local/share/Trash
```

or some path like that, depending on where the mount point is, exactly. You can use the `df`, `mount` or `lsblk` commands to find out where it is mounted.

To log in to a TTY, boot into your Ubuntu, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> (any function key from <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd> would do). You can log in to a terminal and execute the first command, since you should be in your home directory.

Instead of doing an `rm`, you can always use `mv` to move the folder elsewhere. In case you're not feeling too selective, just do:

```
mv .local/share/Trash /some/where/else
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> when you feel a reasonable number of files have been moved.

Comment: You mean mount the troubled parition with the live CD? I've done that and used the command you gave me and is says that there's no such fire/directory. Also, I have no idea how a TTY works or how to even login with one. What if I were to split off some spare disk space with GParted? Would I be able to, say, 'paste' the excess onto the other without losing data; just enough to get me in there and properly empty the trash?

Comment: @PaulLinthicum see update.

Comment: I ran into a pitfall of accidentally deleting .bash_logout . But on the possitive side I manged to clear the trash and get my space back. Required a sudo though.

Comment: @PaulLinthicum a `sudo`? Were you on a live CD? It shouldn't be needed on the TTY. And how did you delete .bash_logout while deleting the Trash?